# overwrite backcolor for ovalshape

Tags: custom-controls, backcolor

I'm trying to use the BackColor variable to fill an OvalShape.
I'm doing this because I need to set the color at runtime and it is the only custom control that uses FillColor instead of BackColor.
The color is changed at runtime using a propertygrid.

I'm overwriting BackColor and it works until I click on the OvalShape.
if I click on the Oval it colors the entire Control not just the Oval.

```
public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (oval == null)
            {
                return Color.Transparent;
            }
            else
            {
                return oval.FillColor;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (oval == null)
            {
                base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                if (sc != null)
                    sc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }
            else
            {
                base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                if (sc != null)
                    sc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                oval.FillColor = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

sc is the ShapeContainer.

I think the problem is that when I click the control is gets the oval.FillColor for the backColor.